# Full control over files sent with ajax in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I use `multer` to parse multiple files sent as `multipart/data-form` with `axios`

```
...

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './gallery',
    filename(req, file, cb) {
      (1) ....
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post('/products', upload.array('images'), (req, res, next) => {

    Product.create(...)
       .then((product) => {
          (2) ... 
       })
       .catch(..)
})

...
```

at this point everything is fine and my images are saved.

the problem is that i want to make a loop in **(1)** or **(2)** and name my files like this

```
files.forEach((file, index) => {

   // rename file to => product_id + '_' + index + '.jpeg'
}
```

For example if i have 3 files they will be named to

```
5a9e881c3ebb4e1bd8911126_1.jpeg

5a9e881c3ebb4e1bd8911126_2.jpeg

5a9e881c3ebb4e1bd8911126_3.jpeg
```

where `5a9e881c3ebb4e1bd8911126` is the id of the product document saved by `mongoose`.

1. how to solve this naming issue ?
2. is `multer` the best solution cause i want full control over my files ?
3. Is there a better approach with another node package ?
4. is it good to send images as `multipart/data-form` or `data URL base64` ?

Comment: multer is just a solution for _temporarily_ save the `multipart/form-data`. Best practice is to manipulate the temp data with your own logic (upload to cloud, change the filename, hash with your own id and store the id in your database, etc).

Comment: @gokcand how to manipulate the data with my own logic without `multer` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy, as long as you understand how express works. So before jumping to solution its important to have a clear understanding.

When you have a express code like below

```
router.post('/abc', function(req, res) {res.send('hello world');})
```

Express passes the request from chains of middlewares/functions. Now each function gets `req, res, next` parameters. The `next` is function, which a middleware is suppose to call when the processing is complete. If the middleware decides not to call `next` the request ends there and no more middlewares are called further.

When we used `function(req, res) {res.send('hello world');}`, we didn't take the `next` parameter at all, which means we are not interested in any other code to do anything. Now getting back to our problem

```
router.post('/products', upload.array('images'), (req, res, next) => {...}
```

You have used `upload.array('images')` first and then your actual product `creation` code. So I would show two approaches to solve this problem

**One more middleware to rename the files**

router.post('/products', upload.array('images'), (req, res, next) => {

```
Product.create(...)
   .then((product) => {
      req.product = product
      next();
   })
   .catch(..)
}, (req, res, next) => {
   //Get the product id using req.product
   //Move the files as per the name you desire
})
```

**Reverse the processing order**

In this approach you first create the product and then let image processing happen. I have created a sample for the showing the same

```
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app = express();
let multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './gallery',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log('Product id - ' + req.product_id);
        cb(null, req.product_id + '.js');
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.all('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Hello you');
    promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        // simulate a async product creation
        setTimeout(() => resolve(1234), 100);
    });

    promise.then((product_id) => {
        console.log('create the product and get the new product id')
        // set the product id in the request object, so the multer
        // filename function can access it
        req.product_id = product_id;
        res.send('uploaded files');
        if (next)
            next();
    });
}, upload.array('images'));

module.exports = {
    app
};

app.listen(8020);
```

And testing it using postman works fine

[image: Postman]

[image: Uploaded file]

**Edit: 19-Mar-2018**

For multiple files you can easily update your filename function code like below

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './gallery',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        req.file_id = req.file_id || 0;
        req.file_id++;
        console.log('Product id - ' + req.product_id);
        cb(null, req.product_id +'_' + req.file_id +'.js');
    },
});
```

This will make sure that you get all the files for that product. Now coming to your questions

> **how to solve this naming issue ?**

This answer already does that

> **is multer the best solution cause i want full control over my files ?**

I can't say, as long it works and does what you want, it should be good enough

> **Is there a better approach with another node package ?**

I couldn't find lot of packages. But you can explore [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) if you want

> **is it good to send images as multipart/data-form or data URL base64 ?**

I would use `multipart/data-form`, so that no base64 conversion is needed at client side. But again this is a matter of opinion as well.

Comment: thanks man :) in the `Reverse the processing order` approch only the last file will be saved because a single `product id` will have many files, i can solve this by concating something like `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: @Youssef, please see the latest edit at the end of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the name purely in `(1)` since at that point you do not know the ID of the product yet.

You can't set the name purely in `(2)` since at that point the files have already been saved (with filename generated by your `filename(req, file, cb)` function).

So I think the best solution might be to *move* the files after they are uploaded.

This could be done in `(2)`. When you process the files in the router, `req.files` will be an array of files that have already been uploaded.

In your promise callback for `Product.create`, you have access to the product (which you need for the ID) and the list of files (which you need for the number).

For that, you could use `fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, callback)`.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

Something like this should work:

```
Product.create(...).then((product) => {
    req.files.forEach((file, index) => {
        // file.path is the full path to the file that was uploaded.

        // newPath is where you want to put it.
        // Let's use the same destination and just change the filename.

        const newPath = file.destination + product.id + '_' + index

        fs.rename(file.path, newPath)
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks man :) can you plz answer the other points in my question ?